# bash: ls: command not found (Usual solutions are not working.)

Tags: bash, terminal, command

I've tried the solutions listed here for instance: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/bash-ls-command-not-found

When I do `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` it works temporarily.

When I do:

```
cd ~
nano .bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH
```

the file changes and the save reflects but when I open a new terminal the commands are forgotten again.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not general computer usage/troubleshooting; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask about this. But also, you'll need to do some troubleshooting yourself: first, are you using bash or zsh as your shell? Based on that, look through the startup files for that shell and try to find out what's messing up your `PATH` in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure your interactive shell is bash, and not something else like zsh? Have you confirmed your `~/.bash_profile` is always being sourced when you open a new terminal?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

@ShaneBishop When I try the command ls, I get "bash: ls: command not found". So I assume it is bash? How do I confirm that it's being sourced?

Comment: use ```~/.bashrc``` - [.bashrc vs .bash_profile](https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/)

Comment: You might be using `zsh` and not `bash`.  Please update your question with the output of `echo $0`.

Comment: source `~/.bash_profile` from `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MaximSagaydachny, you need to use your `~/.bashrc`, not your `~/.bash_profile`.

The commands in your `~/.bash_profile` will only executed for interactive login bash sessions. They will not be executed for interactive non-login shell sessions.

The commands in your `~/.bashrc` will be executed for interactive non-login bash sessions.

For more details, see the ["Invocation" section of the bash man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION).

Therefore, you should add your modifications to `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`.